# Creating a tab or indenting text in HTML within Access VBA for an Outlook email

Tags: html, ms-access

From MS Access 2016 I am creating an email in Outlook and populating the body of the email with content in HTML format.  The client requires the font to be in Arial and certain headings in bold.  This I have successfully achieved. However, I have failed to achieve the insertion of tabs in order to indent text at certain points to get the information aligned.  Have tried quite a few of the suggestions that I could find, but to no avail.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: That has worked a treat - took a bit of tweaking to do a block of text but sussed it in the end.  Very much appreciated your help.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the left-hand margin to indent your text, e.g.:

```
<p style='margin-left:36.0pt'>Your Text Here</p>
```